# Haskell List Concatenation vs. (head : tail) format

Tags: list, haskell

I always wrote my list-producing recursive functions in this format:

```
recursiveFunc :: [a] -> [b]
recursiveFunc (x:xs) = [change x] ++ resursiveFunc xs where
    change :: a -> b
    change x = ...
```

I realize any function like the above could be written for the `a -> b` case and then simply `map`ed over a set `[a]`, but please take this watered-down situation as an example.

HLint suggests replacing `[change x] ++ recursiveFunc xs` with `change x : recursiveFunc xs`.

Is this suggestion purely aesthetic, or is there some effect on how Haskell executes the function?

Comment: Well, with a single element first argument, `++` *will* just `cons` once and then quit, but it's a very roundabout way to prepend a single value.

Comment: Your version has the advantage that if at some point you decide to modify your function such that more than one element is prepended to the list, there is less to change.

Comment: hlint suggestions don't change the result of an expression.

Comment: @DanBurton: Yes, I figured out it did not change the result through testing, but I was wondering how this changed what is happening under the hood.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using `[change x] ++ recursiveFunc xs` you create a superfluous one-element list, which is then taken apart by the `++` function. Using `:` that doesn't happen.

Plus `++` is a function which then will use the `:` constructor. When you use `:` directly, there's no need to invoke a function.

So using `:` is more efficient in theory (the compiler might optimize those differences away, though).

Answer (score 5):

The line

```
recursiveFunc (x:xs) = [change x] ++ resursiveFunc xs
```

is a bit confusing  since it is not in normalform. That means that `++` can be replaced directly with one right hand side of its definition:

```
(++) (a:as) bs = a:((++) as bs)
(++) [] bs = bs

-- =>

recursiveFunc (x:xs) = (change x):((++) [] resursiveFunc xs)

-- =>

recursiveFunc (x:xs) = (change x):(resursiveFunc xs)
```

A Haskell compiler automatically applies such transformation.

But since it is so trivial it makes your code harder to read. One looks at it and asks 'wait ... what?'

Answer (score 4):

The primary advantage is that `change x : blah` is clearer -- `(:)` is precisely what you are trying to do (add one element to a list).  Why call two functions when one will do?

The suggested way is also marginally more efficient -- your way creates a 1-element list and then throws it away and replaces it with a different list link.  The other way just creates one list link.  That said, the difference is small enough to be unimportant 99% of the time.